# Piping commands to smtp server doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, openssl, smtp, pipe

So I was trying to write a bash script to send a mail to someone using smtp.gmail.com server by using openssl.

Everything upto this is working fine:

```
printf "helo gmail.com\nauth plain $auth\n" | openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com -crlf -quiet
```

But the moment I add the mail to command, I am shown with an error.

```
printf "helo gmail.com\nauth plain $auth\nmail from: <username@gmail.com>\n" | openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com -crlf -quiet
```

The error that is shows is:

```
451 4.5.0 SMTP protocol violation, see RFC 2821 lf3-20020a170902fb4300b0019f3141429csm696647plb.160 - gsmtp read:errno=0
```

I have tried a lot of things, including keeping it in capitals MAIL FROM: username@gmail.com, or MAIL FROM:username@gmail.com. Also tried without with the '\n'. Even tried with echo. Also did this instead:

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 -crlf -quiet<<EOF
helo gmail.com
auth plain $auth
mail from: <username@gmail.com>
rcpt to: <anothername@gmail.com>
data

.
EOF
```

But no luck. Have even written a full body too. The problem definitely lies in mail from command.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

SMTP servers are not required to read multiple, consecutive commands, at the same time.

```
printf "helo gmail.com\nauth plain $auth\n"
```

This is going to send this entire string, both commands, all at once, in one blob, to the SMTP server.

This is typical behavior of spamware. Many mail servers will detect receiving multiple commands all at once, like that, and put the brakes on everything. These mail servers require connecting clients to follow SMTP rules, strictly and by the book: send one command, wait for the server's response, and then send the next command. If it immediately reads the next command before it replies to the first one, your goose is cooked.

Additionally, SMTP requires lines to be terminated by `\r\n` instead of just a `\n`, and some SMTP servers will detect this protocol violation too, and tell you to buzz off. This would be another reason for your failed attempt.

There is an SMTP extension called `PIPELINING` that allows SMTP senders to batch up certain commands, and spew it out in one go, but it does not apply here.

To make it work you'll have to do a lot more work in order to emulate an SMTP sender: send one command, wait for the server to reply, then send another command. It should be possible to craft something like that with a shell script, the tricky part will be how to attach the shell script to the TLS wrapper, to redirect both standard input and output to it. This is doable, but will require a lot of finesse.

Comment: so would putting sleep 1 in the code work?

Comment: Only if "work" is equivalent to "sometimes yes, sometimes no". You don't even know how long it will take to establish this SMTP connection, and especially with TLS. DNS lookups can take a few seconds, and a TLS handshake can add a few seconds on top of that. It is not unusual for the first TLS session to take many seconds to establish. There are no shortcuts here. There are no reliable alternatives here to doing everything correctly, by the book.